# Visual Studio Setup Project Installer Prerequisite for SQL Server CE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I have a Setup Project in my solution in Visual Studio 2008 SP1.  The application installs fine but it is not loading my prerequisite of SQL Server CE.

I have the following configurations set:

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/317/msiq.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/317/msiq.png)

Do I need to do anything else, like with a Custom Action or anything like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try private [file–based deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx) (deploying the SQL Server Compact 3.5 DLLs as part of the project) instead.

If you deploy this way you will circumvent this problem and also

- Users do not need administrative credentials to install the application.
- Can also use ClickOnce deployment

Another upside (or in some rare cases downside) will be that the deployment will not be serviced by the Microsoft Update...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have seen this and do not want to use ClickOnce at this time.

Comment: Although I used this type of deployment only with ClickOnce thus far it is my understanding that it doesn't have to be a ClickOnce deployment... it is just a matter of including the dll files in your project instead of using the Windows Installer to install the SQL Server CE to a host machine. As long as you don't **have to** deploy to GAC this should work just fine...

Comment: I'd really like to know why using the prerequisite does not work, but I did get it to work with the file–based deployment.  +1 for a workaround, but hopefully someone can advise on what is wrong with the prereq method.

Answer (score 0):

Choose prerequisites from the same location.